# Why urllib.urlopen doesn't (seem to) work with Stack Overflow?

Tags: python

I need to retrieve my info from Stack Overflow.
The web page that I want to retrieve is something like this.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/260127/prosseek
```

When I run the script, it doesn't seem return any results.

```
import urllib                                       
sock = urllib.urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com/users/260127/prosseek") 
htmlSource = sock.read()                            
sock.close()                                        
print htmlSource
```

whereas I get almost instant result with this.

```
import urllib                                       
sock = urllib.urlopen("http://diveintopython.net/") 
htmlSource = sock.read()                            
sock.close()                                        
print htmlSource
```

What might be wrong?

PS. I don't know wether this should be asked at MetaStackOverflow or not.

Comment: you might want to read up on flair: http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It "works" for me - the page returned is a 404 error. Try putting the URL https://stackoverflow.com/users/XXXXX/prosseek into your browser and see for yourself.

I think you want to use https://stackoverflow.com/users/260127/prosseek instead.

Comment: The XXXXX was 260127, and I just wanted to show some example.
BTW, I used TextMate, and use it to run python to fail. Using command line works well. Thanks,